# Ant The following classes needed for analysis were missing: android.app.Activity

Tags: android, ant, findbugs

Hello i'm trying to run findbugs for my android Project

i already defined

```
<auxClasspath path="${android.jar}" />
```

but findbugs still tries to analize the file, and the var seems not to be defined

```
[echo] ${android.jar}
[findbugs] Executing findbugs FindBugsTask from ant task
[findbugs] Running FindBugs...
[findbugs] Nov 06, 2014 1:52:13 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
[findbugs] The following errors occurred during analysis:
[findbugs]   File not found: filesystem:APPDIRHIDDEN\${android.jar}
[findbugs] The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
[findbugs]   android.app.Activity
[findbugs]   android.view.MenuItem
[findbugs]   android.os.Bundle
[findbugs]   android.view.Menu
[findbugs]   android.view.MenuInflater
[findbugs]   android.util.Log
[findbugs]
[findbugs] Missing classes: 4
[findbugs] Analysis errors: 1
[findbugs] Calculating exit code...
[findbugs] Setting 'errors encountered' flag (4)
[findbugs] Setting 'missing class' flag (2)
[findbugs] Exit code set to: 6
[findbugs] Java Result: 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh now i got it, this variable isnt dynamically set, i have to set it by my self in local.properties or something laike that

```
android.jar=C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar
```